# PHP TZD формат даты [QIWI API]

Tags: php, время, qiwi

Здравствуйте, нужно получить историю платежей Киви, при помощи API. Сделано все, кроме сортировки по времени, здесь я не могу понять. Нужно получить платежи, за **сегодняшний** день.

В API написанно:

**startDate**

> Начальная дата периода статистики. Дату можно указать в любой
>   временной зоне TZD (формат ГГГГ-ММ-ДД'T'чч:мм:ссTZD), однако она
>   должна совпадать с временной зоной в параметре endDate. Обозначение
>   временной зоны TZD: +чч:мм или -чч:мм (временной сдвиг от GMT).
>   Обязательный параметр

**endDate**

> Конечная дата периода статистики. Дату можно указать в любой временной
>   зоне TZD (формат ГГГГ-ММ-ДД'T'чч:мм:ссTZD), однако она должна
>   совпадать с временной зоной в параметре startDate. Обозначение
>   временной зоны TZD: +чч:мм или -чч:мм (временной сдвиг от GMT).
>   Обязательный параметр

Пример запроса:

```
GET /payment-history/v2/persons/79112223344/payments?rows=50
&startDate=2017-05-10T00%3A00%3A00%2B03%3A00&endDate=2017-05-10T23%3A59%3A59%2B03%3A00
```

С этим - **2017-05-10** понятно.

Но как вот это вот - **T00%3A00%3A00%2B03%3A00** получить при помощи PHP? В документации подробной информации нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас просто URL закодирован.

Формат вот такой: `2017-05-10T23:59:59+03:00`

Получить можно так: `echo (new \DateTime('2017-05-10 23:59:59'))->format('c');`
Выведет `2017-05-10T23:59:59+03:00`, если сделать `echo urlencode((new \DateTime('2017-05-10 23:59:59'))->format('c'));` Получим как раз нужную строку

Comment: Большое спасибо, единственное что вам следует поправить, url_encode() > urlencode()